# Java - set an object variable via setter method, but I dont want the ability to change it again

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I have Spring Web Services project, where I have access to the logged in username.

The processes then takes place via several classes, but what I want to do is, set the username in a User class/bean when I first receive it in the first class.

i.e. the following:

**My first web services class:**

```
    // Set the Spring Security Name of the user
    user.setSpringSecurityUsername(request.getUserId());
    String springSecurityUsername = user.getSpringSecurityUsername();
```

**My User class**

```
private String springSecurityUsername = "";
private final String windowsUsername = System.getProperty("user.name");

public String getSpringSecurityUsername() {
    return springSecurityUsername;
}

public void setSpringSecurityUsername(String springSecurityUsername) {
    this.springSecurityUsername = springSecurityUsername;
}

public String getWindowsUsername() {
    return windowsUsername;
}
```

I want to be able create a new instance of the User bean and set the `SpringSecurityUsername`. I then wish to pass the *user* object to the other processing classes, but I don't what them to have access to the setter method in the user (e.g. don't want other classes to be able to use the `.setSpringSecurityUsername`.

I only want to be able to set it the once.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can the value ever be set to null?

Comment: I don't understand why you just can't use a constructor which sets username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I only want to be able to set it the once.

It sounds like you should be passing it to the constructor then. You've referred to the class as a bean in some cases - does it *have* to be a strict JavaBean with a parameterless constructor? Or should everything still work for you if you just add a constructor?

The benefit of putting it into the constructor over ignoring/throwing on a second `setSpringUsername` call is that you simply can't express the incorrect code. It's always better to make something impossible than to have to tell people not to do it :)

(It also means you can make it a final field, too.)

Comment: Thanks for this, could you provide an example please?

Comment: @babb: Which bit do you not understand? You just create a constructor which takes the value as a parameter, and copy that value into a field. You remove the setter completely. Surely you've written constructors before.

Comment: The issue I have is, I am using Spring @Autowired for the User interface. The UserImpl implements User. So in the first class as above, I write user.setSpringSecurityUsername(request.getUserId());         if change to do this through the constructor in the UserImpl class, how to do I set the springsecurityname in the first class?

Comment: Do you *have* to use auto-wiring for `User`? It sounds like Spring is really making your life harder rather than easier here.

Comment: It's just that I wanted to go via the interface, rather than accessing the implementing class directly

Comment: @babb: Well you can still declare that your variable is of type `User` - you'd just be calling the constructor directly. You *may* find there's a way of getting Spring to pass in a constructor argument based on another bean... I'm just not sure.

Comment: After having a go, I agree that the constructor is the best way to go. I agree, something I think my lack of knowledge of Spring and trying to change what I would normally do, doesn't help!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the initializing value should just be a constructor parameter and there should be no setter method at all.  In the case it's also valid to never call the setter, include both a constructor without the argument and one with the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it internally with some value, then in your setter check to see if it still has that value.  If it does, allow it to be set.  If it doesn't it has already been set - simply do nothing in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this, could you provide an example please?

Comment: See answer posted by @JonSkeet, it's better

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the method from being called, but you can check whether it got called previously:

```
boolean usernameSet = false;

public synchronized void setSpringSecurityUsername(String springSecurityUsername) {
    if (!usernameSet) {
        this.springSecurityUsername = springSecurityUsername;
        usernameSet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @djechlin I'm a little rusty on synchronized methods - please remind me why this isn't thread safe.

Comment: I would imagine the boolean `usernameSet` would be used by the getter as well (which may not be the case in this specific setting), in which case the two assignments can happen out of order and produce a race condition.  I think the right pattern would be an `AtomicReference<String>` and use `compareAndSet(null, username)` - fwiw, I think it's okay to post non-t.s. code as long as the reader is warned it needs to be dressed up for threadsafety, but if reader does want t.s. code `synchronized` should be used sparingly.

Comment: ah, right, I was assuming that the getter _wouldn't_ check that variable, as it's initialised to a default (empty) string.  Last time I had to worry about this in anger the `java.util.concurrent` classes didn't even exist...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a requirement of the builder pattern.  You have each setter return "this" and when you want to finalize it you call a method like "finish" to disable all the setters.  Goes like this:

```
new MyClass()
   .setAge(20)
   .setWeight(200)
   .setHeight(6.0)
   .finish();
```

Not a bad pattern at all, kind of gives you named parameters for java without losing the advantages of a immutability.

Comment: Actually the question specifies this kind of behavior exactly (So he's not looking for an EXACT bean pattern). What, exactly, is your objection? Different tools may or may not work correctly with this pattern, but in general it should be fine for the questioners purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go for setting it in constructor and no **setter** methods.

```
public User(String userName){
    this.springSecurityUsername = userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will allow it to be set once:

```
private Object v;

public void setV(Object o) {
    if (v == null) 
        v = o;
}
```

Or if null is a possible value  zfor the first set, do this:

```
private Object notSer = new Object();
private Object v = notSer;

public void setV(Object o) {
    if (v == notSer) 
        v = o;
}
```